# How to pass userDataDir profile folder to Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, e2e-testing, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

I want to pass a custom profile to Puppeteer.
To start I've tried to pass my real Google Chrome profile:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  userDataDir: '/Users/[USERNAME]/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default',
  headless: false,
  slowMo: 250,
  ...
}
```

but when the browser opens if I go to Settings it shows `Person 1` rather than the data from my Google Chrome profile

The userDataDir path above is what is shown in `Profile Path` when on Google Chrome I visit `chrome://version` (where [USERDATA] is my username)

I've tried also userDataDir: '~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default'

I'm using
Puppeteer 0.11.0
Node 8.4.0
NPM 5.2.0
macOS El Capitan 10.11.6
MacBook Pro Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using a relative path worked. The path is relative to the folder where you are executing the cli command running the javascript that uses puppeteer:

```js
await puppeteer.launch({
  userDataDir: './myUserDataDir',
})
```

Comment: I tried the solution it is giving the below error 
[9665:775:0117/220533.630257:ERROR:browser_dm_token_storage_mac.mm(153)] Error retrieving the machine serial number.

Comment: that didn't work! this still creating new temp profile.

Comment: try to play with path.resolve(__dirname, './myUserDataDir')

Comment: I still couldn't get it to work. Turns out the code I inherited included default args were sent to puppeteer. These default args already a default user-data-dir in that points to the temp folder, which came first so Chrome was using the temp dir even though I was specifying something different. I couldn't change the defaults around so the fix I found was to use userDataDir direct with  puppeteer.launch, which takes precedence over the args. Using chrome://version was very useful debugging which profile directory is being used.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late, but there is a simple solution: you need to use back-tick quotes, because 'Application Support' includes a space.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  userDataDir: `/Users/[USERNAME]/Library/'Application Support'/Google/Chrome/Default`,
  headless: false,
  slowMo: 250,
  ...
}
```

The code above will work

Answer (score 0):

```
await puppeteer.launch({
  userDataDir: 'myUserDataDir',
})
```

try using this, it will create a directory automatically.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).