# puppeteer - how to set download location

Tags: node.js, chromium, puppeteer

I was able to successfully download a file with puppeteer, but it was just saving it to my /Downloads folder. I've been looking around and can't find anything in the api or forums to set this location.

My downloads are basically just go going to the link:

```
await page.goto(url);
```

Comment: There is no argument for it yet. Did you try modifying it in the user data directory?

Comment: @AbdullahAlsigar sorry what was I suppose to modify?

Comment: I am not on my pc now, not sure what exactly. Sorry for that.

Comment: @AbdullahAlsigar nw, just let me know where when you're back at your PC and you remember this question lol

Comment: I could not find any thing in the profile folder. another suggestion will be to run puppeteer in headless: false then set your default download folder, I think that should solve the problem.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

##### Update for newer Puppeteer versions (~June 2022):

As mentioned by @Daniel [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72701764/8926214), you have to create the CDP session yourself:

```
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession()
await client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
  behavior: 'allow',
  downloadPath: './myAwesomeDownloadFolder',
})
```

---

##### Original Answer

This is how you can set the download path in latest puppeteer v0.13.

```
await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: './myAwesomeDownloadFolder'});
```

The behaviour is experimental, it might be removed, modified, or changed later.

Pst, you can try more tricks listed [here](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/), on your own risk :).

Comment: Not able to change the download folder. I am placing this line before the download action and providing absolute download path. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Share your code somewhere, probably in a github gist.

Comment: update: 2022
`._client` is not a function, so its not working

Comment: ._client  is not working (at 2022), it should be .client

Comment: Thanks! I've spent half a day trying to get information from ChatGPT. But this is what works!

Answer (score 21):

In newer versions of Puppeteer (I'm using v14.1), the Accepted Answer no longer works:

```js
await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: './myAwesomeDownloadFolder'});

> TypeError: page._client.send is not a function
```

Instead, I had to explicitely create a new [CDPSession](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v14.4.1/docs/api.md#class-cdpsession):

```
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession()
await client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
  behavior: 'allow',
  downloadPath: './myAwesomeDownloadFolder',
})
```

Comment: Heroic. Can't get the `fileChooser` API to work as expected -- this should probably be the accepted answer here.

Comment: When I use this code, with `headless=false`, the browser is failing to download the file with a popup error message: `Something went wrong.` The download works fine without this code, and the file is saved to the Downloads folder on Windows. Any ideas?

Comment: @RyanD On Windows you need to use double backslash for the path to work. This worked for me `downloadPath: "F:\\download\\puppeteer"`

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is an old thread, but this thread popped up first for me when looking for how to set Puppeteer default download location.
I was able to set the download location using the following code,

```
let customChrome = path.resolve(__dirname, './customChrome')
        let prefs = fs.readFileSync(customChrome+'/Default/Preferences');
        let obj = JSON.parse(prefs);
        obj.savefile.default_directory = path.resolve(__dirname, './downloads');
        obj.download.default_directory = path.resolve(__dirname, './downloads');
        fs.writeFileSync(customChrome+'/Default/Preferences', JSON.stringify(obj));
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            userDataDir:customChrome,
            headless: false,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
            args:['--disable-features=site-per-process','--no-sandbox']
        });
```

This will set the default download directory for files before the process starts. Essentially, Puppeteer creates a custom profile each time it runs, we can override that profile and define the download directory.

The first time you run the above code, you will have to comment out the fs.readFile to fs.writeFile as the UserDirDirectory is created if it does not exist the first time that Chrome is started.

All profile related data is then stored in the customChrome/Default folder.
[How to pass userDataDir profile folder to Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46908441/how-to-pass-userdatadir-profile-folder-to-puppeteer)

Answer (score 2):

The answer from [Muhammad Uzair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14085862/muhammad-uzair) solved my similar issue of setting the Chromium user preference to enforce PDF file downloads, but I ran into an issue of setting things up since I am using Puppeteer, Jest, and Jest-Puppeteer, where Jest-Puppeteer handles the initial setup behind the scenes.

This Github post from [Macil](https://github.com/Macil) helped with how to apply the puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences plugin within the `jest-puppeteer.config.js` file.

For example, this is my `jest-puppeteer.config.js` file:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const UserPreferencesPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences');

const userPreferenceOptions = {
  userPrefs: {
    plugins: {
      always_open_pdf_externally: true,
    },
    download: {
      open_pdf_in_system_reader: false,
      prompt_for_download: false,
    },
  }
};
puppeteer.use(UserPreferencesPlugin(userPreferenceOptions));

require.cache[require.resolve('puppeteer')] = require.cache[require.resolve('puppeteer-extra')];

module.exports = {
  launch: {
    // https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v13.3.2/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions
    headless: true, // opens a browser instance
    slowMo: 25, // millis to slow each step
    devtools: false, // auto opens the devtools in the browser
    defaultViewport: {
      width: 1820,
      height: 980,
      deviceScaleFactor: 1,
      isMobile: false,
      isLandscape: true,
    },
    product: "chrome", // can also specify firefox
    browserContext: 'incognito',
    args: [
      // Chromium browser arguments: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/
      '--ignore-certificate-errors',
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
      '--window-size=1920,1080',
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

All given solutions weren't working for me in the newer version of puppeteer `15.5.0`

using `puppeteer-extra` with `puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences` plugin did the trick.

```js
// make sure puppeteer-extra & puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences are installed

const UserPreferencesPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences");

const downloadImageDirectoryPath = process.cwd()

puppeteer.use(
  UserPreferencesPlugin({
    userPrefs: {
      download: {
        prompt_for_download: false,
        open_pdf_in_system_reader: true,
        default_directory: downloadImageDirectoryPath,
      },
      plugins: {
        always_open_pdf_externally: true,
      },
    },
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I run the program in docker container with chrome installed

```
FROM node:18-slim

# ------------------------------------------
# install extension
# ------------------------------------------
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    # chromium \
    # libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget \
    wget gnupg \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# ------------------------------------------
# set global config
# ------------------------------------------
ENV TZ Asia/Hong_Kong
# ------------------------------------------
# change the work directory
# ------------------------------------------
COPY source /root/source
WORKDIR /root/source

# ------------------------------------------
# upgrade npm
# ------------------------------------------
RUN npm install npm -g
RUN npm upgrade

# install node packages
RUN if test -e package-lock.json ; then npm ci ; else npm i ; fi
RUN npm run build
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run"]
CMD ["start"]
```

and

use `await page.target().createCDPSession()` as client for downloading the file
(
ref:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1478#issuecomment-358826932
https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.cdpsession
)

```js
const downloadPath = `[YOU OWN DOWNLOAD PATH]`
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: true,
  args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
  executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'
})

const page = await browser.newPage()
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession()
await client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
  behavior: 'allow',
  downloadPath
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Update 30-07-2022:
An update has been made and this feature has been removed from previous versions of the package as well, if you have downloaded the package before 10-06-2022 it should work. For me it is like that, but it is puzzling why also previous versions were changed ..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).