# Why Puppeteer is not downloading into folder specified with "Page.setDownloadBehavior" in Windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, chromium, puppeteer

I use the following piece of code to achieve the download of a file by making Puppeteer click the button that emits the event

```
await page._client.send(
  'Page.setDownloadBehavior',
  {
    behavior: 'allow',
    downloadPath: './temporal/files/',
  },
);
```

It works pretty fine in a Mac OS machine, but it does nothing in a Windows one

The try/catch that wraps this block it doesn't catch anything, and when I use the `headless: false` setting, it's proven to "download the file", but there is no file in all the hard drive

Comment: did you try '.\\temporal\\files\\' ?

Comment: Actually I did, it doesn't changed anything

Comment: Maybe Windows API needs an absolute path?

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt You are right!, please post the answer so I can voted!!!

Comment: I've posted it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case Windows API needs an absolute path, you can compose it with [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) and relative path.

Comment: `page._client` don't work in newer versions of puppeteer.
I figure out a way to change download path , find answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73153945/14085862

Answer (score 2):

For newer versions (tested in version 12.0.1 on Windows)

`page._client` is deprecated, instead, use `page.client()`

`downloadPath` needs to be absolute for Windows (see the accepted answer)

```
await page.client().send("Page.setDownloadBehavior", {
  behavior: "allow",
  downloadPath: __dirname + "./", // referenced from the accepted answer
});
```

Comment: Please can you explain this code a bit more? the questions is a "why", it needs a "because".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @stramin This answer supports the accepted answer (the 'why' is mentioned there). I wrote this answer for newer versions of puppeteer, where `_client` is deprecated