# How to set download behaviour in PuppeteerSharp?

Tags: c#, puppeteer-sharp

I want to set download behaviour of browser for testing needs

I had tried solution from this topic: [puppeteer - how to set download location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966341/puppeteer-how-to-set-download-location)

```cs
var browser = await StartNewChromeAsync(); //starting new chrome without extensions
var pages = await browser.PagesAsync();
var firstPage = pages[0];
var cdp = await firstPage.Target.CreateCDPSessionAsync();
await cdp.SendAsync("Page.setDownloadBehavior", new
                {
                    behavior = "allow",
                    downloadPath = Path.GetAbsolutePath("./testing_downloads")
                });
await cdp.DetachAsync();
```

I expecting, that files will be downloaded in `./testing_downloads`, but it downloadings in default path.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no way to do this in modern versions of Chrome because Page.setDownloadBehavior is removed from CDP v1.3 https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-3.

UPD: 
this work https://gist.github.com/vabka/88a9b054ee756a53a44691366b16b474

Answer (score 1):

```
//Set the options for download file through puppeteer
                            var options = new LaunchOptions
                            {
                                Headless = false,
                                ExecutablePath = "Path Of Browser to execute, example c://....edge.exe ", //
                                DefaultViewport = null,
                                Args = new[] { "--no-sandbox", "--start-maximized" },
                                
                            };//Launch puppeteer for scrap the Document Data
                                using (var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(options))
                                using (var page = await browser.NewPageAsync())
                                {
                                    await page.Target.CreateCDPSessionAsync().Result.SendAsync("Page.setDownloadBehavior", new
                                    {
                                        behavior = "allow",
                                        downloadPath = directoryToSave
                                        

                                    }, false);


                                    await page.AuthenticateAsync(new Credentials
                                    {
                                        Username = WindowsCredentials.Username,
                                        Password = WindowsCredentials.Password
                                    });

                                    await page.GoToAsync("URL of file to download");
```