# How to specify download directory with pupeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

I'd like to automate the download of some pdf bill in a specific directory but I didn't manage to do it.

Note i'm using puppeteer 3.0.2 on windows:

I tried to setup it multiple ways :
Initializing the browser:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: navMode,
    userDataDir : "E:/projets/factures/",
    args: [
        '--start-maximized',
        // you can also use '--start-fullscreen'
    ]

});
```

I also tried:

```
await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: 'E:/projets/factures/'});
```

juste before the download

i tried also :

```
page.on('request', req => {
    if (req.url() === urlFile) {
        const file = fs.createWriteStream('./file.pdf');
        https.get(req.url(), response => response.pipe(file));
    }
});
```

all of this is before :

```
await page.goto(urlFile); //urlFile contains the pdf url
```

The PDF is only downloading in the Default Download Directory

Answer (score 0):

here I can get solution for you.

[puppeteer - how to set download location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966341/puppeteer-how-to-set-download-location)

In your code,  'E:/projets/factures/' this seems to be error.

Please try use this like './../../projects/fatures/'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use achieve this easily using `puppeteer-extra` & a `puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences` plugin.
please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73153945/14085862) for details