# How to disable or cancel all downloads

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm currently scraping a public webpage in the event that it goes down, and this site has some files where opening them in Chromium will usually download the file to your downloads folder automatically. For example, accessing https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z2201-x64.exe downloads a file instead of showing you the binary.

My code is really complicated, but what the main part of the code is, is this:

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.on("response", async response => {
   // saves the file to a place I want it, but doesn't cancel the chrome-based download.
   buffer = Buffer.from(new Uint8Array(await page.evaluate(function(x:string) {
            return fetch(x).then(r=>r.arrayBuffer())
            }, response.url())));
   fs.writeFileSync('path', buffer);
   return void 0;
});
await page.goto('https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z2201-x64.exe', { waitUntil: "load", timeout: 120000 });
```

I can't just assume the mime type either, the page could go to any URL from an html file to a zip file, so is it possible to disable downloads or rewire it to `/dev/null`? I've looked into response intercepting and it doesn't seem to be a thing based on [this](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1191).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading a bit about `/dev/null` and seeing this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72701764), I figured out that I can do this:

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();
await (await page.target().createCDPSession()).send("Page.setDownloadBehavior", {
   behavior: "deny",
   downloadPath: "/dev/null"
});
```

Setting the download path to `/dev/null` is redundant, but if you don't want to fully deny the download behavior for a tab but also don't want it going to your downloads folder, `/dev/null` will essentially delete whatever it receives on the spot.

I set the download behavior before navigating to a page, and this also focusing on behavior related to Chromium-based browsers, not just mime types.