# TypeError: page._client.send is not a function when setting dowload path

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am getting the error TypeError: page._client.send is not a function when running the following code:

```
await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: library_path, eventsEnabled: true});
```

Full code:

```
function downloadEQData() {
    return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
            try {

                const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'], headless: global_headless });
                const page = await browser.newPage();
                
                // firt we navigate to the page and wait for it to load
                var wait = page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
                await page.goto('https://vendor.equator.com/index.cfm');
                await wait;

                console.log('At FNMA EQ Page');

                // then we log in
                await page.type('#enter_username', global_variables.username);
                await page.type('#enter_password', global_variables.password);

                var wait = page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
                await page.click('button[type="submit"]');
                await wait;

                console.log('Logged In');
                await sleep(6000);

                // hover over workflow
                await page.hover('#menubar > ul > li:nth-child(3)');
                await sleep(1000);

                // click search workflow
                await page.click('#menubar > ul > li:nth-child(3) > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a')
                await sleep(1000);

                // select saved search "2Open Initial Services Wint", id:5126 (comes from the html code)
                await page.select('#selSavedSearch', "5162");
                await sleep(5000);

                // click load search
                await page.click('#btnLoadSearch')
                await sleep(5000);

                // click search
                await page.click('#btnTaskSearch')
                await sleep(5000);

                // allowing download and setting the path to download to
                await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: library_path, eventsEnabled: true});
                
                // this montiors download responses and returns the file name that was just downloaded as fileLink so that we can rename it later
                page.on('response', response => {
                    //check for "Content-Disposition"
                    const disposition = response.headers()['content-disposition'];
                  
                    if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
                      var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
                      var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
                      if (matches != null && matches[1]) { 
                        fileLink = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
                      }
                    }
                  });

                // the selector for the download link changes name so we are searching for the an id that starts with eqDataTabe and contains _excelBtn to clink on
                await page.click('[id^="eqDataTable"][id*="_excelBtn"]');
                console.log('Download Complete')
                await sleep(5000);

                // print out the file name just downloaded
                console.log(fileLink)

                // renaming the file to deliverables.xls
                var file_name ='open_initials_deliverables.xls';
                fs.rename(library_path+"/"+fileLink, library_path+"/"+file_name, (err) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log('Rename complete!')})

                // select saved search "Completed Initial Services Search", id:3426 (comes from the html code)
                await page.select('#selSavedSearch', "3426");
                await sleep(5000);

                // click load search
                await page.click('#btnLoadSearch')
                await sleep(5000);

                // input date
                await page.evaluate((sel,date) => {
                    var el = document.querySelector(sel);
                    el.value = date;
                    }, '#state_date', date)
                await sleep(5000);

                // click search
                await page.click('#btnTaskSearch')
                await sleep(5000);


                // the selector for the download link changes name so we are searching for the an id that starts with eqDataTabe and contains _excelBtn to clink on
                await page.click('[id^="eqDataTable"][id*="_excelBtn"]');
                console.log('Download Complete')
                await sleep(5000);

                // print out the file name just downloaded
                console.log(fileLink)

                // renaming the file to deliverables.xls
                var file_name ='completed_initials_deliverables.xls';
                fs.rename(library_path+"/"+fileLink, library_path+"/"+file_name, (err) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log('Rename complete!')})

                await page.close();

                return resolve();
                

            } catch ($e) {
                console.log('ERROR:' + $e);
                return reject();
        }
    });
}
```

Doing some research I thought it might be an issue with my program versions, but as you can see in the attached image everything seems to be up to date.

```
ERROR:TypeError: page._client.send is not a function
undefined
PS C:\Users\JakeYuraszeck\Desktop\AsseroServicesLLC\Scrapers\EQ Scrapers> node -v
v18.16.0
PS C:\Users\JakeYuraszeck\Desktop\AsseroServicesLLC\Scrapers\EQ Scrapers> npm -v
9.5.1
PS C:\Users\JakeYuraszeck\Desktop\AsseroServicesLLC\Scrapers\EQ Scrapers> npm list
eq-scrapers@1.0.0 C:\Users\JakeYuraszeck\Desktop\AsseroServicesLLC\Scrapers\EQ Scrapers
├── puppeteer-core@19.10.1
└── puppeteer@19.10.1
```

I would really appreciate being pushed in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Nitpicks: `goto` already triggers a wait for navigation, so you have extra code that can cause bugs with `waitForNavigation`. Same with `new Promise`--[you can drop it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). Please [don't sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919013/puppeteer-wait-n-seconds-before-continuing-to-the-next-line/73676564#73676564). `fs.rename` is running after the line after it. I'd use fs promises rather than callbacks. Please include your versions as text, not an image. Thanks.

Comment: As for your main problem, did you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72701764/6243352)?

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks for the notes and link to previous answer. It looks like this is all I need.